# SQL deterministic function that can use SYSDATE ad still be indexed?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, indexing

Consider this example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_age(date_of_birth DATE) 
RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 
    TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, date_of_birth)/12);
END
```

The following query can not be indexed, because `get_age()` is non deterministic.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, get_age(date_of_birth)
  FROM employees
  WHERE get_age(date_of_birth) = 42
```

How can you still use an index to optimize a query for all 42-year-old employees?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Postgresql?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, i'm just learning ... but the example is in oracle

Comment: The answer will be product specific.

Comment: Beyond storing the age as a manually computed column and updating it regularly, there's not much you can do. "Age" is inherently nondeterministic because the result changes with time. Either you or the engine are going to have to keep updating the index.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i was hoping there be trick like indexing in relation to a fixed date, and then subtracting from that fixed date on `WHERE` clause, Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Instead write the query like `SELECT first_name, last_name, get_age(date_of_birth) from employees where date_of_birth between SYSDATE - interval '43 years -1 day' and SYSDATE - interval '42 years'`. Then it will use the index on date_of_birth

Comment: If "42" is a constant in your problem, then you can compute and store the birthdate at which employees become 42 once, and index that. I suppose that, since humans currently don't live that long, this solution could be extended to any desired age...

Answer (score 4):

Put an index on `date_of_birth` and get used to writing the SQL as:

```
where date_of_birth > trunc(sysdate) - interval '43' year and
      date_of_birth <= trunc(sysdate) - interval '42' year
```

This can use an index on `date_of_birth` -- plus it is accurate to the day.

Or to be leap-year safe:

```
where date_of_birth > add_months(trunc(sysdate), -43 * 12) and
      date_of_birth <= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -42*12)
```

Comment: Note: this will fail with `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified` if today is a leap day.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply add keyword `DETERMINISTIC` to your function, then it would work from syntax.

However, your index would work (i.e. provides correct result) only for today! If a person becomes 43 years old tomorrow then next week your query would still return this person as being 42 years old.

As an **ugly** workaround you would have to rebuild the index every day.

Comment: maybe postgres should come with up a determinism test.